# Difference between まで and に when using a Number counter

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions, particle-まで

i wanted to know the difference in nuance between まで and に, when used to represent the number counter, in the following 2 sentences.

四十までアパートに入れます. (Means upto 40 people can enter the apartment)

Vs.

四十にアパートに入れます. (Means 40 people can enter the apartment)

As per my understanding of まで, in the 1st sentence 四十まで is acting as a limiter, i.e. upto 40 people can enter into apartment. In other words, there is a limit of 40 people that can enter the apartment, be it due to size of apartment or other restrictions.

Whereas, when に is used it is just a statement that 40 people can enter the apartment, whereas, there isn't any inherent restriction/limit on the number of people that can enter. E.g. group of xyz number of people will enter first and then the rest 40 can later. However, I am not sure about this reasoning.

Can anyone please tell me the difference between the two?

Comment: ４０にアパートに入れる is ungrammatical. (Too short to answer)

Comment: Can you please tell me how it is ungrammatical, by way of answer because, as I'm using the number counter に can be used

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second sentence is not grammatically sound. The first sentence doesn't sound very natural either. I feel like you would use 四十人 and even then I feel like it sounds kind of odd. I can't really place the reason why though. Did you come up with these sentences by yourself or did you find them in a textbook?

Comment: The まで sentence was out of A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar, the exact sentence was このホテルは二千人まで入れる. Whereas the 2nd one with に, I came that up with myself, because に is also used as a number counter

Comment: @APK Please share the example where に is used.

Comment: The one with に i came up with that, as に is also acts as a number counter.

Comment: @APK I'm not sure what you mean by に being a number counter. Could you please provide another example of に being used as a number counter?

Comment: ごめんなさい、僕はけ研究をした。すると、I found out that my sentence was wrong and に was only restricted to Mark time and i was under a false pretense, that に can be used to mark the "number" of things. I'll delete the post, but before that, thanks a lot for taking the time to reply